# Get Count of Lists in Nested List of Lists

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me with getting the count of Lists in multi-level nested lists.

I used linq to query but i'm getting the count of toplevel list no matter what i do.

My Class is as follows

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Map")]
    public class FieldMap
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "fromPropertyName")]
        public string FromPropertyName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "toPropertyName")]
        public string ToPropertyName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Map")]
        public List<FieldMap> Map { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Items")]
    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item")]
        public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataFieldMapper")]
    public class DataFieldMapper
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Map")]
        public List<FieldMap> Map { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Items")]
        public Items Items { get; set; }
    }

    /**************************/

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Map")]
    public class FieldValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "propertyName")]
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "propertyValue")]
        public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemValue")]
    public class ItemValue
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Map")]
        public List<FieldValue> Map { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Items")]
    public class ItemValues
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemValue")]
        public List<ItemValue> ItemValue { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GenericModel")]
    public class GenericModel
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Map")]
        public List<FieldValue> Map { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Items")]
        public ItemValues Items { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Collection")]
    public class GenericModelCollection
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "GenericModel")]
        public List<GenericModel> GenericModel { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to do something like

```
int count = dict
  .GenericModel
  .Select(x => x.Items.ItemValue)
  .Select(p => p.Select(h => h.Map))
  .Count();
```

I always end up getting the top level count

Comment: What happens when you move the `.Count()` to the nested level?

Comment: @Enigmativity: IEnumerable<int> is the outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flatten your list to get count of all `FieldValue` instances in model:

```
int count = dict
  .GenericModel
  .SelectMany(x => x.Items.ItemValue)
  .SelectMany(h => h.Map)
  .Count();
```

Comment: @RamVenkat difference between `Select` and `SelectMany` is just that flattening of   collection. It allows you to produce MANY elements based on ONE element form parent collection and aggregates results as single collection.